# Is there any way to Inject cookie/session in android app?

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

some times instead of typing password to login I use cookie and inject it using cookie editor on browser /in pc , but is there any way to inject cookie in android app lets say ex :-Facebook

Comment: Shared preferences is a small storage for android apps. You can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Please do **NOT** use localstorage as a password autofiller. It is not safe.
Instead, prepare your app for autofilling passwords and other data by following the [official android instructions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize) .
In such a case, an autofill service like google manages the storage, whilst you provide the hints as where to autofill.

You can also create your own autofill service as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services).

You can read the complete instructions there, but here are some condensed instructions:

tag your input field with the `android:autofillHints` attribute.

```xml
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="password" />
```

or do it programmatically:

```java
EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);
password.setAutofillHints(View.AUTOFILL_HINT_PASSWORD);
```

You can also e.g. link your website login with your app login by hosting a [Digital Asset Link](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links) with a `delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds` relation to your site.

All the above described information is taken from the autofill section on the official android site.